# C++ Sgn Function

Tags: c++

I saw the function below that should return sign of double d. But I couldn't understand how it works?

```
int sgn(double d){ 
    return d<-eps?-1:d>eps;
}
```

Comment: What is `eps`? If you find the definition of that, it might be a clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return d<-eps?-1:d>eps;
```

That means:

- If `d` is less than `-eps`, the result is "negative"
- If `d` is more than `eps`, the result is "positive" (`d>eps` returns 1)
- Otherwise we return 0 (meaning the number is "zero")

`eps` would normally be a small number, so we consider numbers between, say -1e-5 and 1e-5 as "practically zero". This approach is used to water down some deficiencies of the computer's floating-point numbers, like that `sin(pi)!=0`. However, it comes at the cost of introducing an arbitrary number `eps` in the calculation, and losing the property that eg. if `a` and `b` are positive numbers, `a*b` is positive provided underflow doesn't occur.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that eps is a very very small number, around 0.0000000001. If so, the function is using ternary notation to make an abbreviated form of:

int sgn(double d) {
  if (d < -eps) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return d > eps;
  }
}

That "return d > eps" part is probably there to make it return 0 if d == 0.0. Remember that expressions like "a > b" return boolean values, which become 1 if true or 0 if false.

So the function actually could return one of three values: -1 if the number is negative, 0 if it is zero, 1 if it is positive.

Answer (score 2):

FLoating-point arithmetic has some peculiarities, like "[machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)" and `-0` value. This solution uses machine epsilon to determine this '-0' case by using this machine epsilon, but is not completely correct: `-0 = +0 = 0`, always, you don't have to check for it. Also, this `eps` is not defined in your source: I guess It's defined elsewhere.

```
int sgn(double d){
    return d<0? -1 : d>0; # -1, 0, +1. FIXED
    }
```

much simpler, huh? :) in case `d<0` it `return -1`. Otherwise, `d>0` gives either 0 or 1, like `d>0? 1: 0`

P.S. Usually you don't check check the equality of floats: they're not precise and `20.6` can *suddently* (predictable, actually) become `20.000000000001`. However, `double` precision is very high with values close to zero.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write `d>=0 ? d>0 : -1`

Comment: Depends exactly which semantic is determined to be correct, no?

Comment: Well, yes :) But still, extra operations are always, in fact, *extra* ⇒ unnecessary, and wrong if your function sneaks in some loop with millions of iterations :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `eps` is some very small value, really close to 0.

`sgn` function returns -1 is the value is lower than `-eps`, 0 if value is in `[-eps,eps]` and 1 if value is greater than `eps`.

Answer (score 0):

eps is normally a very small value (greek letter epsilon is used in maths for a small increment)

So this says if the d is less than eps (eg. 0.00000001) return -1, else return 1 if it's greater than 0 and 0 if it's exactly 0